# Dynamic Swap Grid Position on Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

The goal is to have an index with swap/zig-zag grid style like this

[image: zigzag]

is there any approach (CSS or jquery) that can make the posts element swapping/zigzag dynamic on the desktop but appears normal on the mobile?

by the way i'm using materialize css and this is my HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 l6">
        <div class="featured-img" style="background-image: url(/img/1.jpg);">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 l6 valign-wrapper">
        <h2>Post Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `display:flex;` and modify `flex-direction` using pseudo-element `:nth-child(even)`. For mobile view you can either utilize `flex-basis` property or use media queries. Check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/wpYeoQ?editors=1100)

Comment: @fen1x thanks for helping me out, i will give it a try and back to you with the result

Comment: @fen1x ~:nth-child(even)~ works like charm thanks